# embedding null if within other null if statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The query below is part of a larger query, but once I add it in, i get a division by 0 error.

```
  (SUM(likes + comments + video_views) / nullif(SUM(influencer_starting_followers),
      0))/ (SUM(average_likes + average_comments + average_views) /nullif(SUM(followers_count),
      0)) AS Achieved,
```

I'm quite new to sql and i'm not entirely sure how to go about changing this section (primarily the denominator as shown below) so that Achieved is only calculated if the query below is not= 0 or null

```
(SUM(average_likes + average_comments + average_views) /nullif(SUM(followers_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second division is not "nullif protected"

```
  (SUM(likes + comments + video_views) / nullif(SUM(influencer_starting_followers),
      0))/ nullif(SUM(average_likes + average_comments + average_views),0) /nullif(SUM(followers_count),
      0)) AS Achieved,
```

nullif returns Null if the 2 parameters are equal, that's to avoid to divide by zero.